# Define Spring 5 Logging Level

Tags: spring, slf4j

I migrated a web-application (deployed on a Web-Server) from Spring 4 to Spring 5. That works fine. No problems in production environment.

But there is a issue in my development-environment:
The development server is running with the JVM option *org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug*. The problem is, Spring "picks up" that option and as a result Spring controllers talk a lot via SLF4J. The amount of debug-output overwhelmed other debug logging. I tried to set separate logging levels for Spring by JVM options like *logging.level.org.springframework.web={info|error|warn|trace}*.

Any ideas or solutions? Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT (see Belistas comment) / Examples:

- DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'project' of type [.Project] to request in view with name 'specs-draft'
- DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/resources/css/style.css] are [/resources/**]

Since everytime a object is added to the model Spring logs with level debug, there is a lot of output.

Comment: level `trace` will even produce more output then `debug`... For the `org.springframework` stuff you probably want `info` or `warn`.

Comment: `logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace` means I want that logging, even more... Did you try to set it to WARN or ERROR levels?

Comment: Sorry, trace was just an example. The same goes for warn, info and error.

Comment: Please share example of such log messages, your application.properties and also logback.xml. Any reason you want to keep that JVM option?

Comment: What is your actual logging framework, which slf4j fallbacks to? Is it Logback or Log4j or JUL? You must configure the actual logging framework.

Comment: I updated the question with examples. I'm not using a application.properties. The reason why I'm using that JVM option is that I can use SLF4J in every project without configuring anything.

Comment: @Amir Pashazadeh: I'm using SLF4J with SLF4J Simple Logger.

Comment: @Flocke I suggest you to use a more feature rich logging implementation (Logback is the most recommended, as it is direct implementation of slf4j). And configuring Logback is like a piece of cake. But I'm not sure about Simple Logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amir Pashazadeh provided the hint that helps to solve the problem.

1. Using Logback instead of Simple Logger
2. Defining a logger for package "org.springframework" in the logback configuration file.

My solution was to ignore Spring debug logging and proceed Spring info logging only by a console output appender.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%-5level %logger{16} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</logger>
```

That's it. Thank you all for your help.